# Possible to live create an dom object with plain JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object  I need to create with JS and later on I need to do an on hover do something statement...And because this div is created clientside later, my hover statement doesn't apply...So my question is, can I somehow live create this just like I was to use jquery.live() but with plain JS?

```
var parentContainer = document.getElementById('box');
var someContainer = document.createElement("div");
someContainer.className = "fun";
parentContainer.appendChild(someContainer);

jQuery("#box").hover(function() {
     jQuery("#box .fun").fadeIn('fast');
});
```

So this obviously does not work because of the live bind issue...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: dude, i am an idiot...I was thinking the wrong way...and total forgot it should have been the hover to set to live to listen for any new dom objects being created....thanks for reminding me....

Comment: Q: Can I somehow do *something from JQuery* but with plain JS?   
  
A: Yes. JQuery is written in plain JS, so anything that JQuery does can be done in plain JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What needs to be live is the `hover` function, not the object.

Live means the event handler is placed at the root of the DOM tree, and if it matches your selector it will trigger.

Read more about how `.live()` works in [jQuery's API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live).